# GPU throws "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES" for any programs

Tags: memory-leaks, opencl, gpu

Whatever program I ran on GPU, even if programs that ran successfully before, my GPU throws this error: CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES for the clEnqueueReadBuffer function.

Then I remembered that I ran a deep learning framework last night which crashed and may ate up all the memory on GPU. I tried to restart the computer, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible that my GPU ran out of memory due to the DL framework's crash?

If so, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: For people who have the same problems as me, I reinstalled Centos and opencl environment, now the bug is gone. But I believe this is the most violent and stupid way, I am sure there is more simple and effective way, if  you figure out, pls let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` is a generic error given by NVIDIA implementation at `clEnqueueRead`, it more or less means:

> Something went out of bounds (resources) when trying to write to this
>   buffer

Most probably the kernel you launched before that writes to that buffer went out of bounds of the buffer.